# How to modify NSTextAttachement 's position in uilabel?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, textkit, nstextattachment

As the picture says, I got two image NSTextAttachments in a label ,and the label has a red background color, If i want to move the image a little down in the label ,how to achieve this?

[image]

(The image above had the bottom truncated because it was white space).

Comment: [myLabel sizeToFit];try this

Comment: in fact ,I want to know whether can I  modify the position the the NSTextAttachment ,because may be sometimes I don't want it to be fit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105803/center-nstextattachment-image-next-to-single-line-uilabel try this.

Comment: I've already try this ,seems not working-_-

Comment: OK,I solved with the answerd in here[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354835/nsattributestring-height-seems-align-wrong-when-use-both-image-and-text

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
- (void)setVerticalAlignment:(VerticalAlignment)verticalAlignment;
```

Comment: I thinks this is effect for the whole label ,but I want just move the NSTextAttachment down or up