# UITextField with a placeholder containing an image and text

Tags: swift, uitextfield

is there any way I could have a magnifier icon stuck to my placeholder in a UITextField like the below:

[image: Search Icon next to placeholder]

I tried to override `leftViewRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect):`

```
override func leftViewRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var superRect = super.leftViewRectForBounds(bounds)
    superRect.origin.x += 80
    return superRect
  }
```

but it didn't work

Comment: try to override `placeholderRectForBounds:`.

Comment: the placeholder is located perfectly, so how would that help me?

Comment: Override UITextField and add a imageview as subview.

Comment: @Justlike You can add images to attributed text like I showed in my answer. No need to subclass UITextField or change any bounds.

Comment: Have you tried using a searchbar instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add images to text using `NSAttributedString` and `NSTextAttachment`.

I haven't used them in a while but I believe you can do something like this...

```
let magnifyingGlassAttachment = NSTextAttachment(data: nil, ofType: nil)
magnifyingGlassAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "MagnifyingGlass")

let magnifyingGlassString = NSAttributedString(attachment: magnifyingGlassAttachment)
```

now you can use the `magnifyingGlassString` attributed string and add it as part of the attributed text to the `UITextField`.

I believe you can also specify exactly how the magnifying glass renders alongside the string (how it wraps etc...)

Something like this...

```
var attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: magnifyingGlassString)

let searchString = NSAttributedString(string: "Search for stuff")

attributedText.appendAttributedString(searchString)

textField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedText
```

Comment: this is a beautiful solution, is there any way the image could be centered with the rest of the text?

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite hi, yes you can do that by subclassing `NSTextAttachment` like is shown here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105803/center-nstextattachment-image-next-to-single-line-uilabel

Comment: I did see that, didn't think it was very elegant. Oh well! thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a image view or a custom view that displays this icon over the text field by properly placing it over and set up appropriate layout constraints. You will be adding this view as a sibling and not subview though.

Comment: So would I calculate the size of the placeholder text, assume it's in the middle and simply place the icon there to the left of the calculated frame?

Comment: So this also works, it's a little more work than the other answer, but if more control of the positioning is needed this is a good method. I should add that it is much easier if the image view is added as a subview rather than a sibling.