# Cant add image as NSTextAttachment to UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield, nstextattachment

I'm trying to add an image as `NSTextAttachment` to `UITextField`, but all I get is `,`

Code within custom `UITextField`:

```
let myAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
myAttachment.image = myImage
myAttachment.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: myImage.size)

let myImageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: myAttachment)
let updatedText = NSMutableAttributedString()
updatedText.append(myImageString)

let myTextString = NSAttributedString(string: ", " + (self.text ?? ""))

updatedText.append(myTextString)

self.attributedText = updatedText
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITextField` will not allow `NSTextAttachment` but `UILabel` allows the `NSTextAttachment`.

[image]

For Example:

```
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
let imageTest = UIImage(named:"user.png")
attachment.image = imageTest
let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "My text ")
let myStringWithImage = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))
myStringWithImage.append(myString)
myTextField.attributedText = myStringWithImage
myLabel.attributedText = myStringWithImage
```

No answers in this apple [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/110740). As of my thought we can enter emojis in text field but not text attachment. In text field we are giving flexibility to user for entering text.

You can use the `leftView` of `UITextField` to display image.

Comment: @AamirR I am also looking for the same but nothing is available. As of my thought we can enter emojis in text field but not text attachment.

Comment: If it is true thats fine, but I wonder why there is a lot of examples on the internet which show how to add an image attachment to text view?

Comment: @zzzkk P.S. TextField and TextView is different. If you have examples please share.

Comment: ahh, yes, I mean text field :) this one fooled me but for `attributedPlaceholder` it really works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897748/uitextfield-with-a-placeholder-containing-an-image-and-text 

so maybe there is not really a lot of them as I said before

Comment: This is not true. UITextField does allow NSTextAttachment

Comment: @RufatMirza Post an answer with your code. This answer 1 year old at that time this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, `NSTextAttachment` isn't appearing in `UITextField`, I am unsure if its a bug or by design of `UITextField`, I will file a radar and update the response here:

Meanwhile, if you can change UI element to `UILabel` and `UITextView`, following works file:

```
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = myImage
attachment.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: myImage.size)

let attributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text ?? "")
attributedStr.insert(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment), at: 0)
```

[image]