# IOS NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName causing strange truncation

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have some `UILabel` that contains a couple of different fonts, which I apply via `attributedText`.

I have set the `lineBreakMode` to be `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` and I have set the size of the `UILabel` to be the `sizeThatFits`

And it looks just fine, until I add `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` to it's `attributedText`

Then I see weird truncation, regardless of how I change the height or width of the `UILabel`

How do I alter the baseline without affecting truncation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Why do NSTextAttachment disappear when setting NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785257/ios-why-do-nstextattachment-disappear-when-setting-nsbaselineoffsetattributename)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the advice from the post, [iOS Why do NSTextAttachment disappear when setting NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785257/ios-why-do-nstextattachment-disappear-when-setting-nsbaselineoffsetattributename)

and added a new `NSMutableParagraphStyle` to the the `UILabel`'s `attributedText` with it's `minimumLineHeight` set to be the font's size plus the added baseline, and I got the results I was looking for.